# Validate only when user enters new data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I just want to ask is it possible to validate specific data in create mode but not in edit mode.

**MODEL**

```
public class FileModel
{
    ......
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You didn't select a file to upload")]
    public IFormFile FileAttachment { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(FileModel file)
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          .....
        }
```

**VIEW**

```
                @{ if (Model.FileID == 0)
                    {
                        <p>Upload new file with this button:</p>
                        <input type="file" asp-for="FileAttachment">
                        <span asp-validation-for="FileAttachment" class="text-danger"></span>
                    }
                }
```

Basically if it is a new model (FileID==0)i want user to select a file.
But if user editing selected file. I don't want him to load file again.

But above code still fails with Model.State even i hide in View.

How can i tell the Model class not to require when file id is 0

Thanks advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET Core, you can simply create a class that inherits from `ValidationAttribute`. You can see the full details in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) .

Based on your requirement ,you can create the attribute like :

```
public class FileAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        FileModel fileModel = (FileModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        if (fileModel.FileID ==0)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return "You didn't select a file to upload";
    }
}
```

And used like :

```
 [FileAttribute]
 public IFormFile FileAttachment { get; set; }
```

Also don't forget to include the `FileID` in form , so that the attribute could get the value after form post :

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="FileID" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I you are editing other properties in the model you can create a view model just for the properties involve. if you want edit the file you should send it to the action as well. if the file can or not be edited you can check if null before model.state check